# Media Querie não é compatível com Internet Explorer 2014

Tags: css3, media-queries

Estou usando as seguintes media queries, no Chrome esta tudo ok. Quais são as propriedades certas para a última versão do IE?

```
@media(min-width:320px) { }

@media(min-width:480px) { }

@media(min-width:600px) { }

@media(min-width:768px) { }

@media(min-width:991px) { }
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Internet Explorer que você usou para testar?

Comment: O mais atual iE 2014

Comment: Diga se o resolve: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />

Comment: @Tony não obteu nenhum resultado

Comment: conhece outro método? estou procurando e nada

Comment: O [Modo de Compatibilidade](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11) esta ativo?

Comment: Se vc estiver usando o IE 10, experimente isso e diga se funcionou pra eu então elaborar uma resposta melhor:
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    }
Depois coloque suas coisas aqui:
@-ms-viewport { width:device-width; zoom:1.0; }

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). Ele é um polifyll para navegadores que não suportam media queries, como o IE. Basta você incluir o arquivo javascript no seu código e tudo irá funcionar perfeitamente. =)

Você também pode optar por utilizá-lo através de um CDN:

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, tentei usar o respond.js mas nada acontece, tu sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Testei aqui o Respond.js e deu certo, porém você tem que usar o servidor pra que ele funcione, se tentar direto localmente no browser não vai funcionar (pelo menos comigo).

Usei esse meta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

e essa cdn depois do css

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Como o site a cima mostra, só a partir do IE9 que media queries são suportados.

Porem há um projeto encontrado no google code que supri como faulback essa necessidade!

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Espero que te ajude!